# How to persist data in react app to minimize server call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In one of my ReactJS page, there are two dropdown menu's, on selecting the value of one or the other, it makes server API call to fetch the data. To fetch the data, i am using `useEffect` hook as below

```
export const useFetch = () => {
const [state, setState] = useState({ data: null, loading: true });

useEffect(() => {
setState(state => ({ data: state.data, loading: true }));
fetch(url)
  .then(x => x.text())
  .then(y => {
    setState({ data: y, loading: false });
  });
}, []);

return state;
};
```

Now, from the drop-down menu's, there are certain number of combinations which can be made to fetch the API data, as the same are not too big with options and for any combination, the value from API is gonna constant, so i need to prevent the API call, if the same combination data had been fetched before and utilize the previous ones only and minimize my component re rendering (this is also one situation if the route changes and it comes back).

Please suggest how to approach in this situation. I have researched on browser's `localstorage` but cleaning the `localstorage` values will be a little problematic if the browser/tab closes, etc

Comment: If your URL contains a specific query for fetching combinations, you can add a cache for your endpoints.

Comment: @MuratErsin `URL' is same, only `POST` body is gonna change. How to check in this situation?

Comment: If is it possible, change endpoint method as GET and set your params as a query string. After this change, I suggest to you axios cache adapter for caching: [axios-cache-adapter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-cache-adapter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you want the data retained on app startup use Redux
- If you want the data retained for the whole session use sessionStorage (will be erased once the browser window is closed)
- If you want the data retained as long is valid use localStorage, in case of need you can clear the storage on *beforeUnload event*

Example:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.handleBeforeunload)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.handleBeforeunload)
  }

  handleBeforeunload() {
      localStorage.removeItem('myItem')
  }
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little about "localStorage as long as its Valid". How to approach in this, validating and invalidating(fetch new and update localStorage) ?

Comment: Has to be read as "localstorage as long you consider it valid". I do not know what's the data trigger that could invalidate your data, is up to you

Comment: beforeUnload has to be triggered on the window

Comment: "beforeUnload has to be triggered on the window", shall i do it in the root component  `App.js` (default name) where `const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");` is called? Will it clear all the `localStorage` value? on closing of tab/browser?

Comment: I've added an example

Comment: i understood about removing the localStorage value, but which place from the entire application, do we need to call that function? I don't want to call it in every component..just one place and that too for browser tab/window close, Sorry, i am new to reactJs and i am using all functional component and hooks no classes..

Comment: you can safely use *useEffect()* hook both in place of *componentDidMount()* and *componentWillUnMount()*